# Is there any way to set JSESSIONID while doing scraping using scrapy

Tags: scrapy, jsessionid

I am writing a code for spider in Scrapy for this website

[ https://www.garageclothing.com/ca/ ]

this website uses jsessionid. 
I want to get that in my code(spider)
Can anybody guide me that how can i get
jsessionid in my code.
Currently i just copy paste the jsessionid from inspection tools of browser after visiting that website on browser.

Comment: Currently I am generating request like that
 yield scrapy.Request(url=my_url, callback=self.parse_cloth,
                             cookies={
                                 'JSESSIONID': 'PV4Q7BMMdZdKCcIscH08jc.com6',
                              }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site uses JavaScript to set `JSESSIONID`. But if you will disable JavaScript, and try to load the page, you'll see that it requests the following URL:

`https://www.dynamiteclothing.com/?postSessionRedirect=https%3A//www.garageclothing.com/ca&noRedirectJavaScript=true` ***`(1)`***

which redirects you to this URL:

`https://www.garageclothing.com/ca;jsessionid=YOUR_SESSION_ID` ***`(2)`***

So you can do the following:

- start requests with the URL ***`(1)`***
- in callback, extract session ID from URL ***`(2)`*** (which will be stored in `response.url`)
- make the requests you want with the extracted session ID in cookies

Comment: Thanks alot dear.
This worked for me.
I spent the whole day finding just this ID

Comment: @mumarKhan if this helped you, could you please accept the answer?